# Printer configured on Lan does not print when system connects through wifi

Tags: 12.04, wireless, printing, lan

I am using 12.04 64 bit. I have noticed if I configure (connect) any printer when my machine is connected to Lan (`eth` port) then it takes print job only if I am connected to Lan. If I try any printing job on wifi, it gets stuck in the print queue. Similarly, when on wifi if I configure the same printer again then it will take print action on wifi, but again if I switch to lan then it will again not print.

So for 1 printer I have to configure two times, one on lan and other on wifi. Also I have to make sure while firing print jobs that I should be selecting right printer by checking the way I am connected to network.

In an ideal situation, any printer configured to machine should take print action on lan as well as on wifi which happens exactly on Windows.

I believe there is something I am doing wrong so please any one correct me....

Answer (score 0):

Are you using wifi through access point or its a routed wifi network? Please provide network configurations for eth0 and wlan0.

Does there exists multiple printers in "Printing" interface? Also mention make and model of the printer. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Robin i am not sure about Wifi architect , but i believe it would be routed wifi network. For eth0 ip Address 169.144.20.246
broadcast address 169.144.23.255
subnet mask 255.255.252.0
default route 169.144.20.1
primary dns xxx.xxx.xxx.

For wifi
ip Address 169.144.15.222
broadcast address 169.144.15.255
subnet mask 255.255.252.0
default route 169.144.12.1
primary dns xxx.xxx.xxx.

Comment: Multiple printers have no impact, as if there is one printer configure then also problem exists and if there is multiple printer then also problem exists. Also we have many different models of printer, so i don't believe model would not have any impact too. Only common thing in all printer is all are of HP and we are using around 15 different models of printer connected to Lan.

Comment: Hi Shashank! From make and model, I meant about whether the printer is network capable or you sharing it through a PC. See problem I can identify is when you connect using wifi, you become part of different network than LAN network, this is due to routing issue in intranetwork. You can add a static route to your ubuntu for wifi interface.

Comment: Hi Robin Yes default route for wifi is different from Lan, but then the same network works perfectly with windows system. On windows system it has no impact whether you are connected with lan or wifi.

Comment: I would recommend you to use http://localhost:631/ cupsbweb interface to install printer and use IPP protocol manually. This should correct this issue. There are multiple printing protocol which are supported by a printer. Using IPP will be as default as in Windows. Do let me know if it worked or not.